# Offline storage for Visualforce pages in Salesforce1

Tags: visualforce, mobile, salesforce1-app

Can Visualforce pages exposed in the Salesforce1 mobile application be opened offline, and if so is there any offline storage available, such as HTML 5 local storage?

Comment: I am not sure, but here some official suggestions from this [Salesforce1 guide](http://docs.developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.186.0.salesforce1.meta/salesforce1/salesforce1_guide_introduction.htm): - *Salesforce Classic remains the best option if you need offline support*, - *use of Custom App (not Salesforce1 Platform) to configure and control complex offline behavior (Mobile SDK only)*

Comment: I'm not sure Salesforce1 itself allows offline access (or would you need to pre-open the VF page before losing connection in this case).

Comment: Having just tested this, it appears that Salesforce1 doesn't like operating offline. While you can specify the pages as being offline, and create a cache manifest, salesforce1 itself will complain that there is no connection to the server when you attempt to open the page. If there's a way to do this, I'm not sure how it's done. The documentation doesn't say anything about offline.

Comment: Seems like Salesforce1 doesn't allow to open a VF page offline, at least I can't open mines. As sfdcfox said I didn't find anything in documentation about it.

Comment: That's a very good question to ask at the 'Salesforce1 World Tour' On the 26th March at Melbourne. You can register from today https://www.salesforce.com/au/events/details/sf1wt14-melb/?d=70130000000hPvg&internal=true

Comment: Any solution for this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Among my contacts at SFDC, this is a "hot" feature request. Somehow here in Germany a lot of people come up with that requirement. At sf1 world tour in London, I attended the breakout session "Salesforce1 Platform Roadmap" and it was said, they are working on that, but at the moment, there is no offline support.

So I would say: no offline support for now. I will verify this on the sf1 world tour in Munich on July 3rd.

Comment: In Munich on July 3rd it was said that it will come soon. But mind Safe Harbor.

Answer (score 3):

first , sorry for my english :s unfortunatly it is a foreign language for me (also I've answered with my Iphone which has a french keyboard).

Second, you can create any visualforce page , declaring a "manifest"  (which list all the files/pages/images you want to be able to load offline) directly in the visualforce page (in the tag   and host the visualforce page in a Site.com website , (or on HEROKU, this is what I do ) . and then , load this page within Salesforce1, Offline. 
I'm currently in a process of validating my Salesforce1 offline package with the Salesforce security review (free app) , but it's taking quite long.

Also, to serve an offline VF, using a weblink or and integration in a page layout seems to be the only way. It seems that lightning is also supporting this feature natively (I think I saw in the manual that the tag name is AppCache).

I'll be happy to share code or to help if you want

Comment: forgot to said, it seems that lightning is also supporting this feature natively ( i think i saw in the manual that the tag name is AppCache) ..
If you want some code sample , do not hesitate to contact me, I'll be happy to share

Comment: sorry last comment, to serve an offline VF, using a weblink or and integration in a page layout seems to be the only way