# Salesforce 1 Visualforce Page offline storage?

Tags: visualforce, salesforce1-app, mobile, html5

1. I know salesforce 1 app provides some navigation/actions javascript library for custom visualforce page inside salesforce 1 app but what about the option for using offline storage? is there anything new available for VF/html5 based apps? I know there is something for hybrid/native apps which is smart store/smart sync.
2. Side Questions, whats the current html5 offline stroage or best html5 offline storage mechanism.

Thanks

Comment: See [this question](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/21206/offline-storage-for-visualforce-pages-in-salesforce1) for additional conversation. Basically, localStorage is supported, but offline pages are not (as of Spring 14, at least). The "best" mechanism for offline storage is the only offline mechanism for storage: localStorage/sessionStorage. Other specs, like SqlLite, aren't uniformly supported, and should only be considered if you plan on using a library to automatically select the best storage option.

Comment: Thanks for the update, I guess salesforce1 app is safe to say not for offline usage since custom development cant be delivered, if the vf page didnt show up in offline mode.

Answer (score 3):

At the moment, Salesforce1 is not capable of serving VF pages offline. This has been discussed [here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/21206/offline-storage-for-visualforce-pages-in-salesforce1) as well.

Quoting the [Salesforce1 guide](http://docs.developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.186.0.salesforce1.meta/salesforce1/salesforce1_guide_introduction.htm): - Salesforce Classic remains the best option if you need offline support, - use of Custom App (not Salesforce1 Platform) to configure and control complex offline behavior (Mobile SDK only)

FWIW, there's an open [idea](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000kyHXAAY) for Salesforce1 offline support if you'd like to vote for it.