# converting visualforce to salesforce1

Tags: salesforce1-app, mobile

I am trying to figure out what it will take to convert an existing app to be compatible with Salesforce1. All there really is online is that you need to hit the checkbox on the edit screen of the VF page. What else needs to be considered to make this a user friend Salesforce1 app?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on your customer requirement.

Lets say you want just mobile look and feel then the approach would be to just style your existing page with CSS friendlier to mobile.You may use plugins like jquery mobile ,polymer,bootsrap .

If you want a responsive UI with better perfomance then would redesign controller to use VF remoting or javascript remoting.This will remove viewstate and make your transaction light .You may consider using frameworks like angular , backbone or knockout to manipulate DOM

Comment: Thanks for your answer, so what if my app already exists... bunch of custom VF pages and I want to make it available on SF1. Should checking the available on SF1 box be enough to at least see the pages and navigate between them? It is somewhat responsive if I access it through the browser

Comment: it's unlikely that your visualforce pages will 1) look good on mobile or 2) be performent on mobile if you did not build the pages with mobile in mind in the first place. But I would suggest that you just mark the boxes "available on mobile" on your visualforce pages and then you will understand what we are talking about. Mohith has summed your best options.

Comment: @user8560 The checkbox just makes VF available on Mobile but there is no magic that will automatically convert your VF to mobile compatible .It is still left to developer to make it compatible to mobile

Comment: Ok, also, you don't HAVE to use JS remoting right? is that just for better performance? What about caching pages? Is that possible?

Comment: Yes you can cache pages using html 5 manifest concept .Js remoting increases perfomance to greater extent .

Comment: it appears SF1 doesnt necessarily allow this: http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/21206/offline-storage-for-visualforce-pages-in-salesforce1

Comment: Currently for standard pages no but for custom VF build you can use caching I believe with app manifest concept

Answer (score 0):

There is a great [slideshow](http://de.slideshare.net/developerforce/visualforce-in-salesforce1-1-1) on slideshare.net which shows some of the best practices for how and when to use Visualforce in Salesforce1. It's not that easy and often requires a huge amount of additional development time.